# How do I get the native HTML5 validation error popups to render for select boxes using Harvest's Chosen class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, jquery-chosen

Ok, so I am currently using Harvest's Chosen JQ select controls, [documented here](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/), for all of my form select boxes. I'm really impressed with these controls, but there is one problem....the native browser validation error popups don't render when there is an HTML5 validation error (which I am using across my application).

I can't tell whether the browser is actually catching the error and trying to display the popup and maybe the Chosen CSS is instructing the browser not to show the select element's error message? On a side note, I can't get the bassistance JQ validation to work with these controls either. I only say that cause I figured someone would recommend I switch to that, which I would rather not do as I am new to JQ and don't really mind the native error popups anyways.

Does anyone have any idea of how I can accomplish this? I don't know if it will take a lot of research/time or if it's a simple answer...I apologize as I am very new to web development in general, but particularly JS and JQ.

Here is an example of the form element with chosen class:

```
<form action="#link" method="post">
  <select class="chzn-select" required>
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="a">a</option>
    <option value="b">b</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

And then I run the following JQuery statement to make it work on page load:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery(".chzn-select").chosen();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the jquery validation library with Chosen
http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate
Chosen hides the actual select HTML element in the DOM. By default the validation library is set to ignore hidden elements.  So just change the default validation to options to something like this:

```
$("#myform").validate({
  ignore: ".ignore"
})
```

As long as you have the required attribute set on your element the jquery validation library will validate it.